# Groovy - Convert a timestamp string to Epoch time in milliseconds

Tags: date, groovy, time, epoch, jenkins-groovy

I have a timestamp string as follows:

```
String build_time=2017-11-20T21:27:03Z
```

I want to convert it into epoch time in milliseconds as per the PST time zone such that my result is:

```
long build_time_ms=1511299623000
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What s the source time's timezone?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried it in Java? (if you know Java ... the reason I ask is that such solutions are readily migrated to Groovy)

Comment: Source time's timezone is GMT @Rao

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this using java's `java.time.*` package. Below is working script and output from running groovy via docker. I haven't tried this within Jenkins though, and script may require adding appropriate `def` statements to avoid pipeline serialization issues

Script

```
import java.time.*

// build time as string
build_time='2017-11-20T21:27:03Z'

// parse and get epoch
time=Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", build_time)

// get epoch milis
epoch_milis = time.getTime()

// create UTC local time
local_dt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(epoch_milis), ZoneId.of('UTC'));

// created zoned time out of UTC time
zoned_dt = local_dt.atZone(ZoneId.of('America/Los_Angeles'))

// get offset in milis
offset_ms = zoned_dt.getOffset().getTotalSeconds() * 1000

// add to UTC epoc
local_timestamp = epoch_milis + offset_ms

println "Time is ${local_timestamp}"
```

Script output, running in groovy REPL

```
$ docker run --rm -it groovy
Nov 21, 2017 3:37:26 AM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
INFO: Created user preferences directory.
Groovy Shell (2.4.12, JVM: 1.8.0_141)
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
groovy:000> import java.time.*
===> java.time.*
groovy:000> 
groovy:000> // build time as string
===> true
groovy:000> build_time='2017-11-20T21:27:03Z'
===> 2017-11-20T21:27:03Z
groovy:000> 
groovy:000> // parse and get epoch
===> true
groovy:000> time=Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", build_time)
===> Mon Nov 20 21:27:03 UTC 2017
groovy:000> 
groovy:000> // get epoch milis
===> true
groovy:000> epoch_milis = time.getTime()
===> 1511213223000
groovy:000> 
groovy:000> // create UTC local time
===> true
groovy:000> local_dt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(epoch_milis), ZoneId.of('UTC'));
===> 2017-11-20T21:27:03
groovy:000> 
groovy:000> // created zoned time out of UTC time
===> true
groovy:000> zoned_dt = local_dt.atZone(ZoneId.of('America/Los_Angeles'))
===> 2017-11-20T21:27:03-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
groovy:000> 
groovy:000> // get offset in milis
===> true
groovy:000> offset_ms = zoned_dt.getOffset().getTotalSeconds() * 1000
===> -28800000
groovy:000> 
groovy:000> // add to UTC epoc
===> true
groovy:000> local_timestamp = epoch_milis + offset_ms
===> 1511184423000
groovy:000> 
groovy:000> println "Time is ${local_timestamp}"
Time is 1511184423000
```

Also, in your example you're giving result of 1511299623000 ms, which seems to be 24 hours ahead of timestamp, looking at javascript console, with inputs from your example

```
new Date('2017-11-20T21:27:03Z')
>> Tue Nov 21 2017 08:27:03 GMT+1100 (AEDT)

new Date(1511299623000)
>> Wed Nov 22 2017 08:27:03 GMT+1100 (AEDT)
```

Comment: Sometimes if you don't need/want the `import` then just try `groovy -e "println new Date().time / 1000"`